# Views communicating with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I am trying to make a sudoku application. It's a fragment based design, in which a fragment hosts a custom view which is a board. I am trying to learn how to build an effective communication within FragmentActivity, Fragment and View

Although a view is created using the FragmentActivity context and I can catch a reference to that context within the current view and then call methods inside FragmentActivity I don't want to tie views so directly to a fragment activity. Instead I want to tie the view to use methods inside a fragment. How can i do that, I can I capture a reference to a fragment and call methods inside that fragment from a view?

Comment: I retagged your post with "android-fragments" instead of "fragment", and "android-view" instead of "views". You should make sure to do this in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I *strongly* recommend that you read through the documentation on [`Fragment`s](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), as you clearly don't understand the whole concept/purpose of using `Fragment`s in the first place (which is OK, because they are confusing the first time you learn them :P).

A lot of your question doesn't make very much sense to me, because I'm not sure what the `View` you are speaking of refers to. What I can tell you is that `Fragment`s have their own UI/layout, along with their own separate lifecycle. So it sounds like you don't want your `FragmentActivity` to interact with the `Fragment`s layouts/methods at all... instead, you should implement the UI's behavior and layout inside of the `Fragment` itself. That is, the `Fragment` will be in charge of updating the UI, receiving click/touch events, displaying information on the screen etc. The `FragmentActivity` will simply hold a reference to the current `Fragment`(s), and will be in charge of displaying/swapping in and out new `Fragment`s as necessary (via the activity's `FragmentManager`).

Hope that answers the question somewhat... read through the documentation a couple times, it sounds like you are just misunderstanding the theory/purpose behind `Fragment`s.

Comment: Okay, maybe I should try to explain this a bit further. I have a FragmentActivity which currently has one Fragment (for now) that fragment holds a custom view subclass (called boardView) which it dynamically adds to it's ViewGroup during runtime.

Comment: OK, so why do you want to manipulate the `Fragment`s layout from the `FragmentActivity`?